# Tricky Issue Handling File Upload in Perl

Tags: perl, post, file-upload, cgi

We use CGI.pm to help us handle file uploading on our website and through our API which is used by our Android & iPhone Apps. We recently noticed that CGI.pm seems to be returning no params for almost 50% of the files being uploaded via our iPhone App. We haven't seen a similar issue with those files being uploaded via our website.

We can't replicate the problem in testing but in production the cgi_error() method of CGI.pm isn't reporting any errors in those cases where the CGI.pm params are missing. We have confirmed that the iPhone App is always including the correct params when POSTing the files for upload.

Quick background on the setup. We have the application delpoyed on Amazon EC2 Servers which are being load balanced using the Amazon Elastic Load Balancers. We also have $CGI::POST_MAX=(1024*100000); so the POST max size is set to 100MB and we have confirmed that all uploads are under this limit.

I'm not sure where to go next. Any ideas on what the issue might be and how to resolve it would be great appreciated. Also helpful would be any ideas on how to identify the root of the issue so we can start troubleshooting.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify your meaning when you say CGI.pm is returning no params for 50% of the files uploaded?  Is that params OTHER than the file data are missing, or that there is simple no data whatsoever available to CGI.pm?  Does the error log show anything wrong for these requests?

Comment: There are absolutely no params returned by CGI.pm even though we have verified that all params are being submitted correctly by the iPhone App. The error log isn't reporting anything and neither is the cgi_error() method which is why we have been so stuck.

Comment: Is that 100MB before or after multipart MIME encoding?

Comment: No idea but the photos being uploaded from iPhone as all less than 10MB so it shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

The loss of params with no error logged is exactly the symptom of the CGI module encountering an error processing the POST data - such as POST exceeding $CGI::POST_MAX. Are you using CGI.pm in functional mode by calling param(), or object oriented mode calling $cgi->param()? Regarding cgi_error(), perldoc CGI warns: *When using the function-oriented interface, errors may only occur the first time you call param(). Be ready for this!*

As for debugging, if you suspect CGI.pm is masking errors from you, try looking at the CGI object before doing anything else:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $cgi = CGI->new();
warn Dumper($cgi);
```

Within the dump of the CGI object you would see an error like this: '.cgi_error' => '413 Request entity too large' - which is what cgi_error() would return for POST_MAX exceeded.

Also, if using Modperl, be aware that CGI can old onto values such as $CGI::POST_MAX between requests to different apps. (But, since you are specifying POST_MAX in yours, this wouldn't appear to be your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

We too are seeing this same behaviour with `CGI.pm`, although we had thought the problem was restricted to just IE. Solved by adding an `$CGI::POST_MAX=5000000`. Over kill as it is only a 50k file being passed back and for.